# TypeScript: Two variables with unknown type, but the same

Tags: typescript

Imagine I have a sorting function with

```
type sortingType = 
    string | number | boolean | { [key: string]: unknown }; // basically unknown

const mySortFun = (a: sortingType, b: sortingType) => { /* do the thing */ };
```

But I know, that if a is type X, then b is also type X. How can I tell typeScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to somehow bind `a` and `b` variables together, like this:

```js
type SortingType =
    string | number | boolean | { [key: string]: unknown }; // basically unknown

type Func = <T extends SortingType>(a: T, b: T) => void;

const mySortFun: Func = (a, b) => { /* do the thing */ };
mySortFun(1, 2)
```

I introduced new type `type Func = <T extends SortingType>(a: T, b: T) => void;` where `a` and `b` have the same generic type T. Now they are coupled together.

If you don't want to have extra type, the option from @captain-yossarian will be really useful:

```js
const sort = <T extends SortingType>(a: T, b: T) => {}
```

Comment: Or you can do `const sort = <T extends SortingType>(a: T, b: T) => {}`

Comment: Your options is much easier to read, don't you mind if I add it to the answer?

Comment: sure, this is why I left a comment and upvoted your answer